# Content of JInternalFrame packed too tightly

Tags: java, swing

When I call `pack()` on a `JInternalFrame` it is not packed correctly, mostly too tight.

Edit:

Here is a minimal example that shows the behavior described above.
It also seems to depend on the used lookandfeel (here: Nimbus).

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class JInternalFrameTester {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
      System.err.println("Failed setting NimbusLookAndFeel");
    }
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JDesktopPane desktop = new JDesktopPane();
    desktop.setOpaque(true);
    frame.setContentPane(desktop);
    frame.setSize(250, 250);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    JInternalFrame iframe = new JInternalFrame("Internal Frame");
    JTextField textfield = new JTextField("Any text here");
    iframe.add(textfield);
    iframe.setVisible(true);
    /* XXX If placed here, it crashes the layouts */
    iframe.pack();
    desktop.add(iframe);
    /* XXX If placed here, the layout is right */
    //iframe.pack();
  }
}
```

[image: JInternalFrame pack test]

Comment: `pack` is using the preferred size of the content to make decisions about how large it needs to be, this would suggest that there is some issues with your content, maybe provide a picture of what you are getting and what you expect

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `pack()` *after* adding the `JInternalFrame` to the respective `JDesktopPane`.

Comment: Shouldn't make a difference, `pack` is using the preferred size of the content to make decisions about how large it needs to be...

Comment: Don't know why, because I can't find it in any manual but I did test it with calling pack() directly before and after adding to the DesktopPane and only the second gave a correct result, don't know if it inherits decoration information only then or something similar..

Comment: And I just rushed through the web for verification and found that I'm not the only one having experienced that: http://jfpoilpret.blogspot.de/2009/02/jinternalframe-lesson-learned.html

Comment: I had almost the same problem with Nimbus (it did not occur with Metal): a `JScrollPane` was set as the content pane of the `JInternalFrame`. Then, with Nimbus, it always showed both vertical and horizontal scroll bars.